# can't connect to other mysql database. Error 1129 was reported

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have a server. And a program running on this server need to connect to one public mysql database. But recently I found the connection failed. And when I want to connect to the database by command
 `"mysql -h *.114.119.174 -u *****"`, 
it will give a error message like this:

> ERROR 1129 (HY000): Host '*.111.74.4' is blocked because of many connection
>   errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

The Host IP shows my server's IP. I tried to increase the **max_connect_errors** to **1000000** and command **mysqladmin flush-hosts** but no use.

What is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you restart the mysql server after making changes?

Comment: yes, I have restart it

Comment: What make me puzzled is will the host be blocked stop me connect to other database?